# Stack snippets with long results overflow question body on mobile with Responsiveness

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, google-chrome

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a [large code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56749325) on a mobile browser and request desktop site
2. Run that code snippet. It should have large `<div>`’s

Then open the code snippet:

[image]

The cards here overflow the snippet’s height and run over the question body. Also tags have a higher z-index.

This happens in [iOS safari too](https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=501959516571)

Device: iOS 12.3.1
Browser: Chrome

Comment: [Works perfectly fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZUvN.png) on Firefox Nightly 68.0a1 on Android 7.0.

Comment: @SebastianSimon If you have chrome installed then can you try that on that too? Maybe this is again just an iOS chrome issue

Comment: No repro on Android chrome

Comment: Seeme like another one of those iOS only issues, I posted